# Проблема при миграции BadMethodCallException : Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::boolen does not exist

Tags: laravel

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('blog_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolen('is_published')->default(false);  // опубликована ли статья          
    });
}
```

```
BadMethodCallException  : Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::boolen does not exist.

  at C:\OSPanel\domains\laravelNew\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php:104
```

Мне надо чтобы по дефолту там стоял false, но мне заместо этого предлагает default на boolen изменить, а мне этого не надо. Версия 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы опечатались, не `boolen`, а `boolean`:

```
        $table->boolean('is_published')->default(false);  // опубликована ли статья
```